# body не меняет цвет

Tags: html, css

У меня появилась проблема - body не меняет цвет.

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  background-color: #636363;
}

.toggle {
  background: #403C3C;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  display: none;
}

header {
  position: fixed;
  height: 96px;
  background-color: #403C3C;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex {
  height: 96px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.logo {
  font-family: 'Revalia', cursive;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 36px;
  line-height: normal;
  color: #E8BB49;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.logo:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #E8BB49;
}

.header-menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: normal;
  color: #E8BB49;
  margin-right: 24px;
}

.header-menu a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #c19a39;
}

.search {
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #E8BB49;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  font-size: 20px;
}

 ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  text-align: center;
  color: #444444;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: normal;
}

 :-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 18- */
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: #444444;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: normal;
}

 ::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Firefox 19+ */
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: #444444;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: normal;
}

 :-ms-input-placeholder {
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: #444444;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 28px;
  line-height: normal;
}

.telegram {
  width: 85px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1700px) and (max-width: 1921px) {
  header {
    height: 124px;
  }
  .flex {
    height: 124px;
  }
  .logo {
    font-size: 48px;
  }
  .header-menu a {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
   ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
   :-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 18- */
    font-size: 36px;
  }
   ::-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 19+ */
    font-size: 36px;
  }
   :-ms-input-placeholder {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1922px) and (max-width: 2561px) {
  header {
    height: 144px;
  }
  .flex {
    height: 144px;
  }
  .logo {
    font-size: 64px;
  }
  .header-menu a {
    font-size: 48px;
  }
  .search {
    width: 400px;
    height: 75px;
  }
   ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-size: 48px;
  }
   :-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 18- */
    font-size: 48px;
  }
   ::-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 19+ */
    font-size: 48px;
  }
   :-ms-input-placeholder {
    font-size: 48px;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 2562px) and (max-width: 4097px) {
  header {
    height: 169px;
  }
  .flex {
    height: 169px;
  }
  .logo {
    font-size: 84px;
  }
  .header-menu a {
    font-size: 64px;
    margin-right: 48px;
  }
  .search {
    width: 500px;
    height: 120px;
  }
   ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-size: 64px;
  }
   :-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 18- */
    font-size: 64px;
  }
   ::-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 19+ */
    font-size: 64px;
  }
   :-ms-input-placeholder {
    font-size: 64px;
  }
  .telegram {
    width: 148px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) (min-width: 1100px) {
  .header-menu a {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .search {
    width: 150px;
  }
   ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
   :-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 18- */
    font-size: 20px;
  }
   ::-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 19+ */
    font-size: 20px;
  }
   :-ms-input-placeholder {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1099px) and (min-width: 1023px) {
  .logo {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .search {
    width: 150px;
  }
   ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
   :-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 18- */
    font-size: 18px;
  }
   ::-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 19+ */
    font-size: 18px;
  }
   :-ms-input-placeholder {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) and (min-width: 320px) {
  header {
    height: 240px;
  }
  .flex {
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 240px;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1023px) and (min-width: 769px) {
  .search {
    width: 150px;
    height: 35px;
  }
   ::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
   :-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 18- */
    font-size: 18px;
  }
   ::-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 19+ */
    font-size: 18px;
  }
   :-ms-input-placeholder {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
  .header-menu a {
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  .logo {
    font-size: 24px;
  }
}

.container {
  width: 1115px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 5415px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Revalia" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<header>
  <div class="flex">

    <a href="#" class="logo">KinoKings</a>

    <div class="header-menu">
      <span>
        <a href="#">Фильмы</a>
      </span>
      <span>
        <a href="#">Сериалы</a>
      </span>
      <span>
        <a href="#">Аниме</a>
      </span>
      <span>
        <a href="#">Комедии</a>
      </span>
      <span>
        <a href="#">Категории</a>
      </span>
    </div>

    <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Поиск по сайту">

    <a href=""><img src="telegram.svg" alt="" class="telegram"></a>
  </div>
</header>

<section>
  <div class="container">

  </div>
</section>

<footer>
  <div class="container">

  </div>
</footer>

<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.8.1/js/all.js" integrity="sha384-g5uSoOSBd7KkhAMlnQILrecXvzst9TdC09/VM+pjDTCM+1il8RHz5fKANTFFb+gQ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Потому что надо подключать сначала чужие стили, а потом свои.

[image: скриншот]